# Split to get only characters in Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, split

I have a string like this :

```
Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal
```

I need to get a var for every words like :

```
$info = "Reporting";
$host = "EXE1";
$device = "BASE";
$status = "Normal";
```

In fact, i saw the function "Split" might be a good use, but i don't understand the patern to use.

Comment: The "_pattern_" in [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a full-blown "_regular expression_", or "_regex_".  You may use a fixed string but you can use a regex.  Having said that, this may well be done with a regex itself.  See a tutorial [`regextut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Comment: @zdim explaining what pattern matching is seems to be today's topic. :)

Comment: @simbabque Indeed!  It's interesting how there are topical days like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this code.

```
my $str = "Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal";
my @fields = split /\s|,/, $str;
my $info = $fields[0];
my $host = $fields[1];
my $device = $fields[2];
my $status = $fields[3];
print "$info\n";
print "$host\n";
print "$device\n";
print "$status\n";
```

Or more compact version -

```
my $str = "Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal";
my ( $info, $host, $device, $status ) = split /[\s,]/, $str ;
print "$info\n";
print "$host\n";
print "$device\n";
print "$status\n";
```

Comment: `split /\s|,/, $str` is more commonly written `split /[\s,]/, $str`, and I think you probably want to split on contiguous sequences of that character class with `split /[\s,]+/, $str`

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use a global regex pattern match instead of `split`. That way you can specify the characters that you're interested in instead of the ones that you want to discard, and there's no chance of a spurious initial empty field if your string happens to start with a separator

It looks like you want to pick out "word" characters, which are upper and lower case letters, decimal digits, and the underscore character. There's a built-in character class `\w` for that, so finding all sequences that match `\w+` should find the data for you

Here's an example program

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $s = 'Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal';

my ( $info, $host, $device, $status ) = $s =~ /\w+/g;

print qq{\$info   = "$info"\n};
print qq{\$host   = "$host"\n};
print qq{\$device = "$device"\n};
print qq{\$status = "$status"\n};
```

#### output

```
$info   = "Reporting"
$host   = "EXE1"
$device = "BASE"
$status = "Normal"
```

If you want to allow more characters than `\w` matches then you could use

```
my ( $info, $host, $device, $status ) = $s =~ /[^\s,]+/g;
```

which matches sequences of characters that are neither space nor comma

Given your sample data the results are identical, but I cannot tell what your real data looks like

Answer (score 2):

Use `split(/\s|,/,"Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal")` to split the string on comma and blank

Answer (score 1):

No need to store the data in an array. Directly create the list and give the variable name to it.

```
my $string = "Reporting EXE1 BASE,Normal";

my ($info ,$host,$device,$status) = split(/\s|,/,$string);

print "$info ,$host,$device,$status";
```

Or else you could use pattern matching

```
my ($info ,$host,$device,$status) = $string =~m/(\w+)/g;
```